# Ie увеличивает размеры (масштабирует весь документ)

Tags: html, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

Сталкиваюсь уже 3й раз с этой проблемой (до этого ее наличие не было столь критично).
Верстаю страницу на localhost (использую openserver), проблема в том что ie увеличивает все размеры, как размеры шрифтов, так и размеры блоков
[скрин chrome](http://postimg.org/image/dr8m2v201/) |
[скрин ie](http://postimg.org/image/bpbn6z5m3/)

обратите внимание на размеры шрифтов в логотипе, отступов и превью альбомов,
размеры  всех элементов специально задал в px чтобы "ну вообще ни шага в сторону", однако IE9 (версии младше боюсь даже смотреть) оказался неформал, собственно вопрос в том как это исправить.

p.s. Используется jQuery, modernizr, less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос можно закрыть, проблема в невнимательности - в IE было установлено значение масштаба - 120%, поэтому и разница в отображении, прошу простить за отнятое время